# pg-promise FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

Есть такой код:

```
var pgp = require('pg-promise')(/*options*/);

var cn = {
    host: 'localhost', // server name or IP address;
    port: 5432,
    database: 'trading_database_eur_usd',
    user: 'postgres',
    password: '7256'
};
// alternative:
// var cn = 'postgres://username:password@host:port/database';

var db = pgp(cn); // database instance;

// select and return user name from id:
db.one('SELECT * FROM eur_usd WHERE OPEN_PRICE > 1.12918;')
    .then(user => {
        console.log(user.name); // print user name;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error); // print the error;
    });
```

После запуска данного файла получаю следующую ошибку:
[image: http://joxi.ru/v29RaqPt3XJbdA]

Как программист я +- новичек и в базе данных не силен.
pg-promise вообще сегодня впервые увидел.
Пытаюсь с чего то начать практику..

На данном этапе просто пытаюсь понять правильный синтакис для работы с этим модулем и базой.
(документация для меня понятна мягко говоря не очень.
Хотя инглиш +- знаю на каком то среднем уровне.)

Вопрос:
В чем моя ошибка в данном запросе? 
Сама таблица выглядит примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. В таблице содержится 5 000 000 строк но памяти у меня 32 гектара стоит и нагрузка во время команды не превышает 20-ти процентов от общего обьема.

Если кто то знает более простые варианты работы с базой данных через ноду - буду благодарен за советы..
Пока что рассматривал еще вариант с node-postgres - там мне работа так же показалась не очень удобной..

Comment: У Node.js память ограгичена, если превышаете 1GB на один Node.js процесс, то и просходит переполнение памяти, как в вашем случае.

Comment: А если это будет многопоточная нода(читал что уже есть она в продакшине) там на один поток будет по гектару или на все про все?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена c помощью добавления св-ва ANY в место ONE:

```
db.any('SELECT * FROM eur_usd WHERE YEAR_MONTH_DAY = \'2003-05-05\';')
    .then(user => {
        console.log(user); // print user name;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error); // print the error;
    });
```

Comment: Это изменение не имеет никакого отношения к проблеме что у вас возникла. У вас проблема простого переполнения памяти - слишком много записей пытаетесь в память затолкнуть.

Comment: Если оно не имеет никакого отношения - то почему после данных изменений память уже перестала переполнятся?
(и все выводится.)